# How to change dropdownItem color in office-ui-fabric-react?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, office-ui-fabric-react

I am new to SPFX and office-ui-fabric-react. I have a dropdownlist with below code and attributes:

```
<Stack tokens={stackTokens}>
     <Dropdown placeholder="Select an option" label="Select a name" options={this.state.items} styles={dropdownStyles} />
</Stack>
```

And here is the `dropdownStyles`:

```
const dropdownStyles: Partial<IDropdownStyles> = {
  dropdown: { width: 800 },
};
```

The [official document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-ui-fabric-react/idropdownstyles?view=office-ui-fabric-react-latest#dropdownitem) is quite complex for me. Could you show me how to change the background color of selected `dropdownlist` item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
const dropdownStyles: Partial<IDropdownStyles> = {
   dropdownItemSelected: { backgroundColor: "red" },
};
```

Comment: oh I was so close. I forgot to wrap the color name with quotation mark. Thank you